# Multidimensional Array delete duplicated key values with condition

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an Array Like this:

```
$ratesData = [
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 2
    ],
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 1
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'amount' => 3
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'amount' => 2
    ]
];
```

I want to keep the duplicated id arrays with cheapest amount, the result will be like this:

```
[
    0 => [
       'id' => 1,
       'amount' => 1
    ],
    1 => [
       'id' => 2,
       'amount' => 2
    ]
]
```

I have a code that works with this problem, but I'm searching an elegant way to accomplish this without all this loops:

```
    foreach($ratesData as $firstLoopKey => $firstLoopValue) {
        foreach($ratesData as $secondLoopKey => $secondLoopValue) {
            if($firstLoopValue['id'] === $secondLoopValue['id'] && $firstLoopKey != $secondLoopKey ) {
                if ($ratesData[$secondLoopKey]['total_amount'] > $ratesData[$firstLoopKey]['total_amount']) {
                    $deleteElements[] = $secondLoopKey;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($deleteElements)) {
        foreach ($deleteElements as $element) {
            unset($ratesData[$element]);
        }
    }

    $ratesData = array_values($ratesData);

    return $ratesData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `amount` descending and then extract the array indexing by `id` which will eliminate the duplicates with the lowest `amount` overwriting the higher:

```
array_multisort(array_column($ratesData, 'amount'), SORT_DESC, $ratesData);
$ratesData = array_column($ratesData, null, 'id');
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [amount] => 2
        )
)
```

I always like having the key the same as a unique `id` to make array access/sorting easier, but you can re-index if needed:

```
$ratesData = array_values($ratesData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some simple solution:

```
// your source array
$ratesData = [];
// result array
$filtered = [];

foreach ($ratesData as $v) {
    $id = $v['id'];
    // if this is `$id`, which is not in `$filtered` yet
    // or value of `$filtered[$id]['amount']` is greater then current `$v`
    // then replace `$filtered[$id]` with current `$v`
    if (!isset($filtered[$id]) || $filtered[$id]['amount'] > $v['amount']) {
        $filtered[$id] = $v;
    }
}

echo'<pre>',print_r(array_values($filtered)),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution

```
    $uniqueRates = [];

    foreach ($ratesData as $rateData) {
        $key = $rateData['id'];
        if (!\array_key_exists($key, $uniqueRates) ||
            $rateData['total_amount'] < $uniqueRates[$key]['total_amount']
        ) {
            $uniqueRates[$key] = $rateData;
        }
    }

    return array_values($uniqueRates);
```